# How to take product name or product type from user and Assign some value on that product in C so that I calculate that value with other's price

Tags: c

I want to make a program where I can calculate some calculations like,

1. how much I spent
2. how much I saved from my budget,
3. and how much I spent extra from my budget,
   **4. and want to take(From user) some product name and their price(That amount I spend on them)So that I can calculate them with the other predeclared value and other prices.**

**N.B. I clear 1-3 problems but I'm stuck in no 4. if anyone could help me that would be great.
Thanks in Advance**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int shirt,pant,jacket,snikers,jogers,tshirt;
    int budget,save,Total_spend,over_cost;
    printf("Please at first Tell me your Total Budget:");
    scanf("%d",&budget);
    //shirt section
    shirt=500;
    printf("\nThe price of the shirt's price was predicted to : %d$",shirt);
    printf("\nPlease tell how much you spend on The shirt:");

    scanf("%d",&shirt);

    if (shirt==500)
    {
        printf("Hurray!! you spend %dTK which is absolutely same as you predict on shirt",shirt);
    }
    else if (shirt>500)
    {
        printf("ouh o!! shirt price is %d.\nthis is more than the budget. You spend %d$ more TK on shirt ",shirt,shirt-500);
    }
    else if (shirt<500)
    {
        printf("Mamma Osthir!! shirt price is %d.\nthis below budget. You save %d$ TK on shirt",shirt,500-shirt);
    }
     /*else
     {
         printf("price is below budget");
     }*/


    //pant section
    pant=700;
    printf("\n\nThe price of the pant's price was predicted to : %d$",pant);
    printf("\nPlease tell how much you spend on The pant:");

    scanf("%d",&pant);

    if (pant==700)
    {
        printf("Hurray!! you spend %dTK which is absolutely same as you predict on pant",pant);
    }
    else if (pant>700)
    {
        printf("ouh o!! pant price is %d.\nmore than the budget.You spend %d$ more TK on pant",pant,pant-700);
    }
    else if (pant<700)
    {
        printf("Mamma Osthir!! your pant price is %d.\nthis pant price is below budget. You save %d$ TK on pant ",pant,700-pant);
    }

    //Extra bought Section
    /*string v;
    printf("Please Tell me if you buy anything else extra");
    scanf(“%[^\n]s”,v);
    printf("%s",v);*/







    //Total i spend


    printf("\n\n\nTotal Budget was= %dTK",budget);
     Total_spend=shirt+pant;
    printf("\n\The total Amount you spend that is= %dTK", Total_spend);
     if (budget>Total_spend)
     {
         printf("\nyour total savings is =%dTK",budget-Total_spend);
     }
     else if(budget<Total_spend)
     {
         printf("\nYou Didn't make any savings, you Totally over_cost =%dTK",Total_spend-budget);
     }







     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a do-while loop get the amount spent for every extra item and add it to Total_spend.
If you also want to save the name of the item with its price, create 2 arrays , one for the names and one for the prices.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).